# p-n junction depletion region

Tags: semiconductor-physics

My Textbook reads:

> During forward biasing, holes move towards n side and electrons move towards p side. The **diffusion of electrons and holes into the depletion layer decreases its width.**

If more holes and electrons will diffuse, wouldn't they form more immobile ions i.e. increase the width of depletion region. How come this decreases its width?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily show that the width of the depletion layer is given by $$W=\sqrt{\frac{2\varepsilon}{q}\left(\frac{N_a +N_d}{N_a N_d}\right)V_{bi}},$$ where $N_i$ is the acceptors/donors atoms density and $V_{bi}$ is the built-in voltage. If you forward bias the p-n junction, equation above modifies as follows: $$W=\sqrt{\frac{2\varepsilon}{q}\left(\frac{N_a +N_d}{N_a N_d}\right)\left(V_{bi}-V\right).}$$ So you can see that high forward bias voltage $V$ means decreasing of $W$.

Comment: So depletion region disappears when $V>V_{b}i$?

Comment: Yes, something new happens in this case (saturation).

Comment: why it is not like $V_{bi} + \Delta V_{bi}  - V$, i.e.  why doesn't $V_{bi}$ increases due to external voltage?

Answer (score -1):

I think you missunderstand the meaning of "diffusion" in this context. It simply says that **holes and electrons are pushed further into depletion region** due to electromagnetic forces acting on them.

They are not dissappearing, which the unfortunate phrasing of the sentence from your book might suggest.

See this wikipedia article about [Diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion) as a term used in mechanical engineering context.

Comment: No. Diffusion is due to a concentration gradient and random walks. Not due to a Coulomb force.